# Printing 1D Array onto Column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am looking across numerous columns and rows and inputting cell values of interest into a 1D array. I would just like to print this array of length 2020 into a single row on another worksheet. I am not sure why my program is not working, but I appreciate any help

```
Sub Math()

Dim FW_List() as Variant

x = 0

For i = 3 to 10
    For j = 17 to 282
        If Left(ws.Cells(j, i).Value, 3) = "0.7" And ws.Cells(j, i).Interior.Color <> 8696025 Then
            ReDim Preserve FW_List(x)
            FW_List(x) = ws.Cells(j, i).Value
            x = x + 1
    Next j
Next i

num = UBound(FW_List) - LBound(FW_List) + 1
Debug.Print num

wb.Sheets("JMP").Range("A1:A2020").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FW_List)
End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of the problem you're having.

Comment: *my program is not working* is not a useful problem description. In what specific way is it *not working*? Do you get errors? If so, what is the exact error message? Do you get incorrect output? If so, what output do you expect, and what are you getting instead? If you don't clearly explain the problem you're having, it's very difficult to help you find a solution. This site requires a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, and you've not yet produced that, explained the problem clearly, or asked any sort of specific question. Please [edit] your question to provide that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite good but it lacks precision. Some of the changes I made are cosmetic, like the use of a With statement to shorten the code and thereby make it easier to read. But the nonchalance with which you approached variable naming probably caused your failure. Observe that I retained both structure and logic of your original code.

```
Sub Math()

    Dim FW_List     As Variant
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet
    Dim C           As Long                 ' loop counter: column
    Dim R           As Long                 ' loop counter: Row
    Dim i           As Long                 ' index of FW_List
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    ReDim FW_List(1 To 3000)                ' any number larger than what you expect
    
    For C = 3 To 10
        For R = 17 To 282
            With Ws.Cells(R, C)
                If Left(.Value, 3) = "0.7" And .Interior.Color <> 8696025 Then
                    i = i + 1
                    FW_List(i) = .Value
                End If
            End With
        Next R
    Next C
    If i Then
        ReDim Preserve FW_List(i)
        Worksheets("JMP").Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, i).Value = Application.Transpose(FW_List)
    End If
End Sub
```

But here are two things you probably couldn't have known.

1. `Dim FW_List As Variant` creates a variant which, as you know, can be anything including an array. Therefore `Dim FW_List() As Variant` creates an array of such variants. Since any of its components can do what the whole structure does the idea isn't useful and therefore any difference it can make not beneficial.
2. When you `Redim Preserve` an array the entire array is re-written to a new one, element by element. As the size of your array grows to 2020 elements that process eats time if repeated 2000 times. Therefore my code creates an array intentionally larger than what is needed and then truncates unused elements - a process I believe is done without re-writing the array at all.

Comment: Nice.  Not sure you need the final Redim, since you're only filling from the "used" part of the array?

Comment: Good point. Habit, I suppose. If not trimmed, the empty elements of the array would be written to the sheet where they over-write cells which are presumably either empty anyway or should be.

Comment: #like, but I don't consider the `With statement` cosmetic

Comment: Only the part of the array which "fits" in the destination range gets written: adjacent cells would not be affected.

Comment: It used to be that the size of the array must have the exact size of the range one writes to. That was a good logic, too. I wouldn't write code in the hope that Microsoft won't change the rules back to what they were before.

Comment: Thank you @Variatus for your thorough code. I agree that I could have added more specificity, but I just wanted to convey my message. Also thank you for your two points at the end, I was not aware of those facts.